# QDataWidgetMapper and validation

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I have a tree view with several columns.  I use a QDataWidgetMapper to connect each column with one of several widgets on a sidebar.  Data can be changed by double-clicking on a cell in the tree view or by using the widget on the sidebar.

One of my columns has string data that needs to be validated.  I created a custom delegate, which I attached to both the tree view and the data widget mapper.  It has a QRegExpValidator, to prevent invalid input while the user is typing.  Also, in setModelData(), it has a different validation check for once the user has pressed "Enter".  For the tree view, this delegate works fine.  For the mapped QLineEdit, there are two problems:

1. The QRegExpValidator does not get called (presumably because createEditor() is not used for the sidebar widget); so the user can type in bad input to the QLineEdit.
2. If the data fails the check during setModelData(), the text in the QLineEdit does not switch back to the original text.  So when the user clicks on something other than the QLineEdit, the error message gets printed again.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Here is a simplified example.  I replaced the tree view with a list view for simplicity:

```
class TestWidgetMapperValidate(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestWidgetMapperValidate, self).__init__(parent)

        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)

        # Set up the list view
        self.listView = QtGui.QListView()
        self.listModel = QtGui.QStringListModel(['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'])
        self.listView.setModel(self.listModel)

        # Set up the delegate
        self.testDelegate = TestDelegate()
        self.listView.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, self.testDelegate)

        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.listView)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)

        # Set up the QDataWidgetMapper
        self.mapper = QtGui.QDataWidgetMapper()
        self.mapper.setModel(self.listModel)
        self.mapper.addMapping(self.lineEdit, 0)
        self.mapper.setItemDelegate(self.testDelegate)

        self.listView.selectionModel().currentChanged.connect(self.mapper.setCurrentModelIndex)

class TestDelegate(QtGui.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

    def createEditor(self, parentWidget, option, qModelIndex):
        editor = QtGui.QLineEdit(parentWidget)
        nameRegex = QtCore.QRegExp('[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+')
        editor.setValidator(QtGui.QRegExpValidator(nameRegex))
        return editor

    def setEditorData(self, editor, qModelIndex):
        value = qModelIndex.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        editor.setText(value)

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, qModelIndex):
        if not editor.hasAcceptableInput():
            return False

        oldValue = qModelIndex.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
        newValue = editor.text()

        if oldValue != newValue:
            if newValue in model.stringList():
                print 'That name already exists: {0}'.format(newValue)
                return False
            else:
                return model.setData(qModelIndex, newValue)
        else:
            return True
```

(Note: I am using PySide and Python 2.7)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I came up with.  I don't know if it is the best solution, but it works for my case.

1. I ended up adding a QRegExpValidator directly to my line edit, since I couldn't get it to read the one from the delegate.  Here are the updated lines from __init__():

   ```
   class TestWidgetMapperValidate(QtGui.QMainWindow):
       def __init__(self, parent=rsui.getMayaMainWindow()):
           # some code omitted here
           self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit()
           nameRegex = QtCore.QRegExp('[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+')
           self.lineEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QRegExpValidator(nameRegex))
   ```
2. If the data fails the check in the delegate, I call setEditorData() with the original value to force it back to the old value.  This prevents the error message from being printed twice.  Here is the updated setModelData() from the TestDelegate class:

   ```
   def setModelData(self, editor, model, qModelIndex):
       if not editor.hasAcceptableInput():
           return False

       oldValue = qModelIndex.data(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole)
       newValue = editor.text()

       if oldValue != newValue:
           if newValue in model.stringList():
               # The new value is not valid.  Set the data back to the original value.
               self.setEditorData(editor, qModelIndex)
               print 'That name already exists: {0}'.format(newValue)
               return False
           else:
               return model.setData(qModelIndex, newValue)
       else:
           return True
   ```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it:

1. `QDataWidgetMapper` is used to map model data to existing widgets. Therefore, as you mentioned, the delegate method `createEditor` is never called. Stated another way: `QDataWidgetMapper` is used **instead of** using the delegate method `createEditor` in conjunction with a view. An alternative approach would be to create a view for your sidebar, register your delegate with it (such that the view calls `createEditor`) and share `tableView`'s selection mechanism. See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#sharing-selections-among-views.
2. If you were to create a sidebar view as suggested above, you could handle the event that `setModelData` returns false, in your case by restoring the editor value.

I have to admit, I am relatively new to Model-View. I am interested to hear from others on this. It's a great question!